# Javascript : .css jquery video inversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to invert the incoming image(Actually video) through URL. When I try inverting image in HTML, It just invert HTML's button. I think maybe it defined as background. What I want to know is how to invert image(video) defined background. Here is my source.

**Source**

```
$("body").css("background-image", "url('" + streamImageUrl + "')");
```

`streamImageUrl` is URL that defined as `?action=stream`.

In short,

proc 1) Reverse up and down my image.

proc 2) Turn left and right image what reversed in proc 1.

Thank you.

Comment: Where is your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Set the background image in a separate element spanning the width and height of page and `position: fixed`.

Use CSS3 `scaleX` or `scaleY` set to `-1` to respectively flip the element horizontally or vertically.

You can also use CSS3 `rotateX` and `rotateY`.

**Example: http://jsfiddle.net/oqy2L73u/**

Answer (score 0):

Use [`transform: rotate3d()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate3d) to rotate any HTML element.

```css
iframe {
  transform: rotate3d(0,1,10,180deg);
}
```

```html
 <iframe width="420" height="315"
src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lgZBsWGaQY0?autoplay=1">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using css [`transform`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp).

```js
$('#rotateVideo').click(function(){
  $('video').toggleClass('rotatevideo');
});
$('#mirrorVideo').click(function(){
  $('video').toggleClass('mirrorvideo');
});
```

```css
.rotatevideo{
  -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(1800deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}
.mirrorvideo{
  -moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay src="https://cdn.glitch.com/237f9e5e-9593-4123-a05c-eff4a2b38f99%2FCaliper_logo_video.ogg?1499957478610"></video>
<br/>
<button type="button" id='rotateVideo'>Rotate Video</button>
<button type="button" id='mirrorVideo'>Mirror Video</button>
```